# Finding distance around land between 2 sets of points in r

Tags: r, for-loop, distance, raster

I am trying to find the distances between two corresponding sets of points (i.e., locations where fish were tagged and locations where they were recaptured, giving distance travelled). Some of the points require finding the closest distance around land. This will be for over 500 sets of points.

Example data:

```
    tagxy <- data.frame (Y_tagged  = c(45.141, 45.311, 44.954),
                      X_tagged = c(-65.501, -65.221, -66.014))
    
    recapxy <- data.frame (Y_returned  = c(43.187, 43.295, 43.279),
                       X_returned = c(-65.754, -66.051, -66.348))
```

Visual:
[image]

I have been following the 'Distances around barriers' section on the following webpage which requires you to convert the shapefile you are using into a raster: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/three-ways-to-calculate-distances-in-r/.

Raster I am using (visualized above):

```
library(fasterize)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(maptools)

na <- ne_countries(scale = "large", continent = "North America", returnclass = "sf")

r <- raster(extent(na), nrows = 10000, ncols = 10000)

rraster <- fasterize(summarize(na), r)
```

In the example, they first find the cells that the coordinates correspond to in the raster, convert the cell with the point of interest to = 2, and then use gridDistance() to calculate distances from the point of interest (i.e. with value = 2) to all the rest of the coordinates in the same columns, omitting anything with a value = 1 which would be land.

```
icell <- cellFromXY(rraster, tagxy)

rast_pts[icell[1]] <- 2 #changing the first value in icell to = 2

d <- gridDistance(rraster, origin = 2, omit = 1)
```

This code works for me, however what I need is to be able to find the distance between corresponding points in a different set of columns. I was thinking if I converted the corresponding coordinates (i.e., where fish#1 was tagged and then recaptured) in the raster to both = 2, then somehow find the distance between matching values while still omitting land (value = 1). gridDistance() only has an origin point, however, so I'm not sure what would be the best function for this.

Brainstorming potential next steps:

```
tagcell <- cellFromXY(rraster, tagxy) # get raster cells for tagging coordinates

recapcell <- cellFromXY(rraster, recapxy) # get raster cells for recapture coordinates
  
rraster[tagcell[1], recapcell[1]] <- 2 # convert corresponding coordinates (first values of both sets) to both equal 2
```

Alternatively, I can get the cell numbers of the raster that correspond to the coordinates for both tagging locations ('tagcell' above) and recapture locations ('recapcell' above), so if there is a way to find distances between corresponding sets of raster cells that can omit land (=1).

The second part of this problem is that I then need to repeat this for 500+ corresponding points. I assume producing a for loop that pulls in both sets of coordinates and the raster layer would be the best call?

I really appreciate any help I can get with this! Rasters and for loops are new to me. I'm open to suggestions!